# How to get local file revision in perforce workspace by using cmd

Tags: perforce

I've noticed that a file's revision is not latest in p4v,so I wonder is there any way to get the revision of a local file by using cmd since p4v already have done it.

I've already checked all the p4 commands like "filelog",but all of these command return info of depot file instead of local file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `p4 have` to see what revision of a file you have in your workspace (i.e. the revision you last synced from the depot).  Like most commands that operate on files, this takes a file argument so you can limit it to a specific file; by default it reports all the files you have in your workspace.

You can also use `p4 sync -n` to "preview" a sync, which will tell you whether there are files that you don't have the latest revision of.

Comment: It works good and simply.Before your answer, I tried to get the latest changelist of my workspace and compare to the changelists from "p4 filelog" to solve this problem.I have tried "p4 have" command before but it not work.Now I have known that I just need to change my cmd client to p4v's  to make it work.

Comment: If you launch the command window from P4V, it'll set up the P4 environment for you automatically.

Comment: I use p4 command in C# by starting a process and maybe I have done some changes to the client. I guess that's the reason why my client not set right. Anyway, the problem is solved. I will check the client before using cmd next time. Thank you for your help.